# Unicode Error in Java?

Tags: java, unicode

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            char c = 'Q';
            int j = c;
            System.out.println(j + " " + c);
        }
    }
```

The above code outputs 81 Q, but I thought Q is 51 in Unicode? what's happening?!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?  It's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

51 is hexadecimal for 81 (5*16 + 1 = 81).  Q is 81 in decimal, 0x51 in hex, U+0051 in Unicode, which are all the same thing.

See for example the entry for Q on [this page](http://www.alanwood.net/demos/ansi.html).

Answer (score 0):

'Q' is 81 decimal value, 51 hexadecimal value. Applies to ASCII, ISO 8859-1 (Latin 1) and in UTF-8.